# How to only add 2 cells in a column below a cell with certain text

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add two new cells in a column below a cell with certain text? I can add rows using the code below, but I want to change it to add two new cells instead, is this possible?

```
Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Range("B:B")
    If c.Value Like "YIELD" Then
    c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
  Next c
```

Comment: That is the kind of situation where you should do it manually while recording a macro, just to see what method Excel calls (and which what parameter to shift cells down).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that. I did try recording a macro (I usually do to see & understand the code) but for some reason I couldn't work out how to place it in the routine. Many thanks, works great. Regards Roger

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B:B")
    If c.Value Like "YIELD" Then
        c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next c
```